# GNU make 3.82 run time error on Ubuntu-20.04: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: gnu-make, ubuntu-20.04

I downloaded gnu-make-3.82 from [GNU](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-3.82.tar.gz) and make & install it on a specific directory (e.g. dir) on my Ubuntu-20.04 machine.

Then I run

```
$file dir/make
```

It returns:

> ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=ef2934bdbc32938713fd4cb1c9a733e8b6785af0, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped

When I run

```
$dir/make --version
```

It returns:

```
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

When I run it with even the simplest Makefile, it generates the error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Why? What additional work I need to do to make it work well?

Answer (score 1):

According to tips from @steeldriver, I made the following changes to dir.c.

```
diff --git a/dir.c b/dir.c
index adbb8a9..c343e4c 100644
--- a/dir.c
+++ b/dir.c
@@ -1299,15 +1299,40 @@ local_stat (const char *path, struct stat *buf)
 }
 #endif
 
+/* Similarly for lstat.  */
+#if !defined(lstat) && !defined(WINDOWS32) || defined(VMS)
+# ifndef VMS
+#  ifndef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
+int lstat (const char *path, struct stat *sbuf);
+#  endif
+# else
+    /* We are done with the fake lstat.  Go back to the real lstat */
+#   ifdef lstat
+#     undef lstat
+#   endif
+# endif
+# define local_lstat lstat
+#elif defined(WINDOWS32)
+/* Windows doesn't support lstat().  */
+# define local_lstat local_stat
+#else
+static int
+local_lstat (const char *path, struct stat *buf)
+{
+  int e;
+  EINTRLOOP (e, lstat (path, buf));
+  return e;
+}
+#endif
+
 void
 dir_setup_glob (glob_t *gl)
 {
   gl->gl_opendir = open_dirstream;
   gl->gl_readdir = read_dirstream;
   gl->gl_closedir = free;
+  gl->gl_lstat = local_lstat;
   gl->gl_stat = local_stat;
-  /* We don't bother setting gl_lstat, since glob never calls it.
-     The slot is only there for compatibility with 4.4 BSD.  */
 }
```

Then remake the make and run it. It works fine without any warnings or erros.